# How to change font colour for Chartjs labels

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I've created a pie chart in chart.js and can't figure out how to change the font colour for the count number inside each pie slice. Here's my code

```
const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          pointStyle: "rectRounded",
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: "Use of App",
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function (context: any) {
            const label = context.label || "";
            const value = context.parsed;
            const total = context.dataset.data.reduce(
              (a: number, b: number) => a + b,
              0
            );
            const percentage = calculatePercentage(value, total);
            return `${label}: ${value} (${percentage})`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add fontColor to the object in question:

```
fontColor: "blue",
```

---

```
const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          pointStyle: "rectRounded",
          fontColor: "blue"
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: "Use of App",
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: function (context: any) {
            const label = context.label || "";
            const value = context.parsed;
            const total = context.dataset.data.reduce(
              (a: number, b: number) => a + b,
              0
            );
            const percentage = calculatePercentage(value, total);
            return `${label}: ${value} (${percentage})`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Comment: I did try putting fontColor: ["red", "white"] under pointStyle, as you mentioned and it did not work. I also tried putting  "labels: {color: "#fff", } under the plugins line, above legend and that also did not work